# Modified value of a row based on a given condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a dataset with two columns (`type` and `subtype`)

```
structure(list(Pathology = c("Bladder", "Bladder", "Bladder", 
"Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-  / EGFR - / AR - / PD-L1 -)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / AR - / EGFR -)", 
"Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 1% / FGFR -)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 2%)", 
"Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PDL1 - / AR -)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 50% (Breast and IC 5% liver))", 
"Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)"), simple_pathology = c("Breast ()", 
"Breast ()", "Breast ()", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)", 
"Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)", 
"Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want the type column to be the same, except when it starts with `Breast` substring, in which case I want to substitute it by the subtype column.

So in the e.g. above, the output would be:

```
type                                subtype
Bladder                             Breast ()           
Bladder                             Breast ()           
Bladder                             Breast ()           
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)          Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
if (subset(dat, startsWith(Pathology, "Breast"))) {
  dat$Pathology <- dat$simple_pathology
} else {
  dat$Pathology <- dat$Pathology
}
```

Comment: Could you please share these data by pasting `dput()`? You will likely get faster, better responses this way.

Comment: Thank you @jpsmith. That's a cool function I just discovered

Comment: can you please explain the desirable output?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question @RoyBatty279, though it appears your `dput()` represents your desired data, not the original data.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple subssetting replacement with the aid of `stringr::str_starts()`

```r
require(stringr)
#> Loading required package: stringr

breast.index <- str_starts(dat[["Pathology"]], "Breast")
dat[["Pathology"]][breast.index ] <- dat[["simple_pathology"]][breast.index]

dat
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    Pathology                  simple_pathology          
#>    <chr>                      <chr>                     
#>  1 Bladder                    Breast ()                 
#>  2 Bladder                    Breast ()                 
#>  3 Bladder                    Breast ()                 
#>  4 Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#>  5 Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#>  6 Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#>  7 Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#>  8 Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#>  9 Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#> 10 Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can modify in place using `mutate` and `if_else` as well:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate(Pathology = if_else(str_starts(Pathology, 'Breast'), simple_pathology, Pathology))
```